# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User' not found in Lumen 5.6

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm migrating an API from Laravel 5.6 to Lumen 5.6
My app use a plugin of mine that reference `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

but Lumen doesn't seem to have it. Is it normal ?

```
(1/1) Error
Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User' not found
in HasRelationships.php line 656
at Model->newRelatedInstance('Illuminate\\Foundation\\Auth\\User')
in HasRelationships.php line 418
at Model->belongsToMany('Illuminate\\Foundation\\Auth\\User', 'competitor', 'championship_id')
in Championship.php line 87
at Championship->users()
in Builder.php line 546
at Builder->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
at call_user_func(object(Closure))
in Relation.php line 89
at Relation::noConstraints(object(Closure))
in Builder.php line 550
at Builder->getRelation('users')
in Builder.php line 518
at Builder->eagerLoadRelation(array(object(Championship), object(Championship), object(Championship), object(Championship)), 'users', object(Closure))
in Builder.php line 498
at Builder->eagerLoadRelations(array(object(Championship), object(Championship), object(Championship), object(Championship)))
in Builder.php line 466
at Builder->get(array('*'))
in Relation.php line 154
at Relation->get()
in Relation.php line 143
at Relation->getEager()
in Builder.php line 529
at Builder->eagerLoadRelation(array(object(Tournament)), 'championships', object(Closure))
in Builder.php line 498
at Builder->eagerLoadRelations(array(object(Tournament)))
in Builder.php line 466
at Builder->get(array('*'))
in BuildsQueries.php line 77
at Builder->first()
in CompetitorController.php line 35
at CompetitorController->index('fake-tournoi')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CompetitorController), 'index'), array('fake-tournoi'))
in BoundMethod.php line 29
at BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
in BoundMethod.php line 87
at BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(object(Application), array(object(CompetitorController), 'index'), object(Closure))
in BoundMethod.php line 31
at BoundMethod::call(object(Application), array(object(CompetitorController), 'index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi'), null)
in Container.php line 564
at Container->call(array(object(CompetitorController), 'index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi'))
in RoutesRequests.php line 373
at Application->callControllerCallable(array(object(CompetitorController), 'index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi'))
in RoutesRequests.php line 339
at Application->callLumenController(object(CompetitorController), 'index', array(1, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\CompetitorController@index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi')))
in RoutesRequests.php line 313
at Application->callControllerAction(array(1, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\CompetitorController@index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi')))
in RoutesRequests.php line 275
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array(1, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\CompetitorController@index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi')))
in RoutesRequests.php line 260
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(1, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\CompetitorController@index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi')))
in RoutesRequests.php line 230
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(1, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\CompetitorController@index'), array('slug' => 'fake-tournoi')))
in RoutesRequests.php line 164
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in InjectDebugbar.php line 65
at InjectDebugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 151
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CorsMiddleware.php line 18
at CorsMiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 151
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php line 410
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('App\\Http\\Middleware\\CorsMiddleware', 'Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar'), object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php line 166
at Application->dispatch(null)
in RoutesRequests.php line 107
at Application->run()
in index.php line 28
at require('/Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/kz-api/public/index.php')
in server.php line 147
```

EDIT:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
...
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'competitor', 'championship_id')
            ->withPivot('confirmed')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

If I change `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` for `App\User`, it will work, but as this code belongs to a plugin, it is recommended never to make reference to `App\User` as you never know the namespace of the project in which it will be running

Comment: Try `composer update --no-scripts` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: it didn't change anything

Comment: Double check [the lumen authentication docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication). For `Auth` to work, you need to use `auth` middleware and you need to uncomment `auth` middleware in the `bootstrap/app.php`. Also, I don't think you have `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` available in lumen, but I could be wrong. It's been a while since I've used lumen..

Comment: Please, show the code which fails.

Comment: code is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. `laravel/lumen-framework` doesn't pull in `laravel/framework` it pulls in the submodules from `Illuminate`, which do not include what is in `Illuminate\Foundation`.

Comment: it is sad :( So, the only thing I can do is asking the user to configure where should be the User model ?